# MySQL Index percentage against total records

Tags: mysql, indexing

About what percentage of records out of total records is an index in MySQL effective? E.g, If i have a total of 18,000,000 records of employees and want to perform a filtered search on employees with salaries greater than 50,000. If about 10 million (> 50%) of employees have a greater salary, then an index on salary would not do much good anyways. What is a good percentage to consider before creating an index? 10%, 30%, 40%?

A reference to the source of documentation addressing this would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago it was a fixed number of ~30%, but these days it involves more complicated heuristics.

But still, something over 20% should be considered as a potential fullscan.

In your particular case - simply create an index and check with `EXPLAIN` whether it is used or not.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: And... There is usually only minimal harm in simply leaving the `INDEX` in place.